# The 'Vacancies' table in the database 'LiveDb' is not enabled for SQL cache notification

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am running an asp.net application and getting this error:

**The 'Vacancies' table in the database 'LiveDb' is not enabled for SQL cache notification.
Please make sure the table exists, and the table name used for cache dependency matches exactly the table name used in cache notification registration.**

I tried this on command line:

```
**C:\Users\myuser>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319/aspnet_regsql.exe
C:\Users\myuser>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319/aspnet_regsql.exe -S
 localhost -U myuser -P password -d mydb -ed
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET SQL Registration Tool version 4.0.30319.18408
Administrative utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET features on a SQL server
.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    Enabling the database for SQL cache dependency.

.


Finished.**
```

but still same error.

Please suggest solution

Comment: @TomTom I tried exec AspNet_SqlCacheRegisterTableStoredProcedure 'vacancies' but still same error. I am new to cache dependency and tried several links from google search but still same error. Thanks for the commenting.